# Factory Method pattern with unique_ptr member of a abstract class and Copy constructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Suppose I have a setting with Abstract class ApplicatonBase which has a unique_ptr to another abstract class DocumentBase:

```
class ApplicationBase
{
public:

    void factoryMethod()
    {
        _doc->doSomething();
    };

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<DocumentBase> _doc;

};

class DocumentBase
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
```

Now I develop concrete classes RichDocument and RichApplication as follows:

```
class RichDocument : public DocumentBase
{
public:
    void doSomething() override
    {
         std::cout << "I'm rich document\n";
    }
};

class RichApplication : public ApplicationBase
{
public:
    RichApplication()
    {
         _doc = std::unique_ptr<RichDocument>(new RichDocument());
    }

    RichApplication(const RichApplication& other)
    {
        /*
         * TODO: I want to copy the data from other document
         *       unique_ptr and give it to the current document
         *       unique_ptr
         */

         //Following crashes as the copy constructor is not known:
         // error: no matching function for call to ‘RichDocument::RichDocument(DocumentBase&)
         //_doc.reset(new RichDocument(*other._doc));
    }
};
```

The problem is in the copy constructor. I want to deep copy the data in the unique_ptr in copy constructor. Is there a way to do that? Or should I change my structure? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can define a virtual `unique_ptr<DocumentBase> DocumentBase::clone()` method. Or you can use static polymorphism (i.e. `template<class Document> class Application {...` (note that switching to static polymorphism is a big decision that will require a completely different way of structuring your code)

Comment: @enobayram See the following way: 
`class DocumentBase
{
...

    virtual std::unique_ptr<DocumentBase> clone() const
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<DocumentBase>(new DocumentBase(*this));
    };
};`

and

`class RichDocument : public DocumentBase
{
...
    virtual std::unique_ptr<RichDocument> clone() const
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<RichDocument>(new RichDocument(*this));
    }
};`
Bit compiler errors : cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘DocumentBase’. This is because of the pure virtual function. Any workaround?

Comment: @enobayram Even if in the above clone methods, I remove the abstractness of the class, I have the following error:
invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual std::unique_ptr<RichDocument> RichDocument::clone()

Comment: @N.Biyani the `DocumentBase` class shouldn't implement the `clone` method, only the `RichDocument` should, and you should return a `std::unique_ptr<DocumentBase>` from it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are pairing up `RichDocument` and `RichApplication` in the class hierarchy, you should be prepared to do one of the following:

- Accept any base document when constructing a rich document, or
- Reject all documents except `RichDocument`.

Assuming that the only way to initialize `_doc` is in the constructor of `RichApplication`, the second approach should be good enough:

```
RichDocument *otherDoc = dynamic_cast<RichDocument*>(other._doc.get());
// We created RichDocument in the constructor, so the cast must not fail:
assert(otherDoc);
_doc.reset(new RichDocument(*otherDoc));
```

Comment: What's the point of using `dynamic_cast` if you're not going to check the result? Why not just use `static_cast` instead?

Comment: @enobayram When `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr` you are pretty much guaranteed a crash on the next line. When `static_cast` fails silently because the type is wrong, the program may crash at some other place. I guess an explicit assertion wouldn't hurt, though.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about the crash. f.x in this specific case, it would probably not crash since `RichDocument` has no members, so the copy constructor won't be following the null pointer.

Comment: @enobayram You are probably right, `*otherDoc` is constructing a reference, not a value, so the fact that the reference is invalid may go unnoticed unless `RichDocument` tries to follow it.